# What's the difference between using a pre-initialized list for iteration and using an ienumerable/iqueryable for iteration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For example i have a CustomDataContext class with the following DbSet:

```
public DbSet<CustomClass> Classes { get; private set; }
```

What's the difference between the following 2 cases?

Case 1:

```
using (var context = new CustomDataContext())
{
    var something = ....;
    var sql = $"SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE condition = {something}";
    var items = context.Classes.SqlQuery(sql).ToList(); // <--- ToList()

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
using (var context = new CustomDataContext())
{
    var something = ....;
    var sql = $"SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE condition = {something}";
    var items = context.Classes.SqlQuery(sql); //  <--- No ToList()

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any benefit of iterating directly on an ienumerable/iqueryable object in terms of performance? I know what happens in Case 1 but i don't know what happens in Case 2. Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: ToList() does a foreach through the query and adds each result to a `List<CustomClass>`. Without that, when you get to your own foreach, the query hasn't been executed yet. It's just waiting to be executed. If you're blocking for this entire method, there won't be any difference in performance. Constructing the `List<CustomClass>` won't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: So there's no difference in performance even when i'm working with a lot of elements (e.g. 500k+) ?

Comment: Can you describe some cases you've seen where putting a foreach loop in a different method affected its performance, but only on a large number of iterations?

Comment: Take a look at my solution Ed, as there would be noticable differences in the performance.

Comment: @ShaneDemskie OK, so, maybe I wasn't clear. I apologize. When I said "putting a foreach in a different method", I didn't actually mean "a foreach ***on a totally different query*** in a different method. I just meant what I said. I wasn't meaning to suggest that *any foreach loop on any query at all, anywhere* has identical performance to any other. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: No need for apologies, Ed! I see what you're saying and totally agree, the iteration of the data isn't where the performance increases would be seen.

Comment: One thing to note is that `ToList` has to actually create a `List` and all the objects the query returns in memory, where `AsEnumerable`/`foreach` can convert the buffered SQL results on the fly into an object as each is processed.

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerable describes behavior, while List is an implementation of that behavior. When you use IEnumerable, you give the compiler a chance to defer work until later, possibly optimizing along the way. If you use ToList() you force the compiler to reify the results right away.

For the example you listed, there is no discernable performance difference.

The performance comes when we take advantage of the deferred execution. LINQ doesn't generate the SQL to query the database until you enumerate it.

Consider the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<Vehicles> CaliEmissionStd()
{
    return from a in EPA.RoadVehicles
           where a.emissions.CaliEmissions == true
           select a;
}

public IEnumerable<Vehicles> Cars(IEnumerable<Vehicles> vehicles)
{
    return from a in vehicles
           where a.VehType == "Car"
           select a;
}
```

Here, we have a method that selects all road vehicles with cali emission standard, and a filter that selects a sublist of type car.

Since LINQ holds off on constructing a query until we enumerate it, we can do the following so that we end up with a single SQL query, which queries the database and will only returns the rows that are relevant.

```
var AutosWithCaliEmissionStd = Cars(CaliEmissionStd());
```

But if we had returned a List from `CaliEmissionStd()`, then it would  run slower because the database would be returning data for all vehicles with cali emission standard(Cars, SUV, Trucks, Motorcycles, etc), instead of just Cars, causing us to waste cycles/time doing the filtering in the client.